# How to create a column that's filterable from a Content Query Web Part

Tags: column, content-query-web-part

I have an App of type 'Document Library', on which I added a column of type 'Managed Metadata'.
I am using the Content Query Web Part to display documents matching a certain metadata tag.

Unfortunately, in the filters of the Content Query Web Part, the column I created for my Document Library App doesn't appear.
This remain true even if I set the Content Type of the query to 'Document Library'.

Is there a special way to create column that will make them filterable ?
xoxo !

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the column will have to be created as a site column to show up in a CQWP. If you created the column in the document library only, it will not show up as a filterable column.